# Bloomberg-like Excel function

Tags: excel, bloomberg, vba

I would like to create VBA function that works like Bloomberg API.
That means the function can return a value to excel while waiting for results from server.
When server has return with a value, the cell value will be updated with server results.

I have managed to program the part with UDF making asynchronous server call and I am getting results. But it is taking a long time fetching results from server. I would like to make these functions more user friendly to return intermediate results while waiting.

Can anyone enlighten me how I can do it? Thanks.

Cheers,
Ken

Comment: It would help to show your existing code. Likely you would need to make all your server calls asynchronous.  The more-difficult part might be to find some way to trigger a recalculation to refresh the UDF results (assuming you mean to create a UDF)

Comment: Maybe start here: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/#_Toc173749363

Comment: Thanks Tim. In Bloomberg, the API function can have multiple asynchronous return at different time. E.g. while waiting it will release control to user and show "N/A Requesting...".I have implemented what is shown here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/enus/library/office/ff796219(v=office.14).aspx 

but however I try, it only allow a single return and not multiple. So I am trying to seek help to do multiple asynchronous return.

Answer (score 0):

Bloomberg provides a solution for this called Excel AppPortal, but you will need to write your code in C#.

Otherwise, you will need to write an RTD (RealTimeData server for Excel)